# Synchronizing Exchange WebService Managed API method calls

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have written a listener class which creates an HTTP listener and subscribes its URL to push subscriptions (on new mail event on Inbox using EWS Managed API), receives notifications, processes mails and then move those mails to Deleted Items folder. I have also written a poller which periodically checks for any mails left out inside the inbox, processes them and then moves them to the Deleted Items folder. Listener and poller run in different threads.

I have synchronized these threads using locks. And the lock functionality is tested to work fine. However due to locking I am getting some undesired behavior.

Consider listener receives a push notification. It starts processing it. Meantime, poller starts and it acquires the lock. Now when listener tries to acquire the lock it finds that the lock is already acquired by the poller. So it waits till lock gets freed. Say listener executes till instruction `INSTR-1` and continue waiting. Now poller is processing all mails in inbox for say 3-5 minutes. After that, poller releases the lock. In those 3-5 minutes, exchange continues to dispatch push notifications, however since first listener thread is stuck at `INSTR-1` no more listener threads are dispatched by .NET runtime. But as soon as poller releases lock, all threads gets dispatched. But since their corresponding mails have been already processed and moved to Deleted Items folder by the poller, those listener threads throws the exception “The specified object was not found in the store.”  on `EmailMessage.Bind()` method. Since I have now well analyzed this behavior and I know exactly why this exception is occuring, I can simply go on to suppress these exceptions (say with empty `catch` blocks).

However I will like to know,

1. if there is any way by which I can make Exchange Server to not to dispatch any push notifications after poller starts or in other words for those mails which have been already retrieved by EWS Managed API call `ExchangeService.FindItems()` made by poller.
2. if there is any standard / Microsoft recommended way  to handle such problems

We can visualize the listener and poller procedures and execution behavior as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To answer #1, the short answer is NO.  There is no PAUSE functionality for receiving Push Notifications.  You can't even Unsubscribe temporarily because there is no Unsubscribe for Push.  (Not that you would want to in all likelihood.)

To answer #2, it would be pretentious of me to speak for MS, but all I've read suggests you should be doing the minimal amounts of work in your listener and poller.  All these threads should be doing is getting the ItemId involved in the notification or email you're interested in, and queuing that up for further processing (Get, Move, Delete, etc.)  Holding a lock for 3-5 minutes in general is not a good practice.  (Locks should be held for milliseconds, if possible.)  If you queue the ItemIds and have a separate thread (or threads) to process them outside of the poller/listener, that would be a more robust solution, IMHO.

Comment: yess bloody right point, I didnt thought that, I think this should be the design approach related correction, but then I will like to know **1.** if suppressing exceptions with empty catch block will be fine or not? (at least for what I have built already) and **2.** can you see any temporary small design improvement in this current solution?

Comment: Suppressing those particular exceptions is not a problem.  In fact you can likely come across many cases of "object not found" because Exchange's internal workflow likes to create and destroy many objects, even tho they may in fact only deal with a single email item.  My app deals particularly with appointments, and one meeting invite and accept cycle might create 3 distinct ItemIds within the store, 2 of which no longer exist by the time I field the notifications.  So I just take the attitude of "good riddance," and figure the "last man standing" is what I really care about.

Comment: I just thought more about ur approach. And I feel it will cause some duplications, to avoid which, I used locks, though without ur approach. So by ur approach let us consider Listener & poller are running in different threads fetching mails from Inbox and then adding it to the dictionary keyed on `ItemId`. Now say listener adds `item1` to  the dictionary, and a processor running in another thread takes that mail and starts processing it. Meanwhile poller wont be able to add same `item1` to dictionary....

Comment: ....Processor ends processing, deletes the mail from Exchange Server and removes `ItemId` from the dictionary. After this poller will never find item1 in Exchange. But there is time duration between poller starts fetching all mails in inbox and trying to add the `item1` in dictionary. Now during this time if processor removes item from the dictionary, poller will successfully re-add `item1` to dictionary, since it was being removed by processor....

Comment: ...Next time when processor tries to re-process `item1`, it will not be able to fetch the full mail corresponding to the `ItemId` of `item1` and that will throw exception. I think I will have to employ another empty catch block there. Any comments? Is this the way you implemented it?